# the Double Series $\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis

the Double Series $\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges?

We know that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converge to $\pi^{2}/6$, then $\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$, converges or not?

Comment: With regards to $m$ this series is constant, so it can not converge, but I do not exactly know, what you mean by the notation $\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\sum_{m=1}^\infty1$, which does not converge because $\sum_{m=1}^\infty1$ diverges.